# MySQL report/cause error when update finds no rows to update?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there a way to make MySQL cause some kind of error when doing `UPDATE` and there no rows matching condition? `UPDATE` returns affected rows, and it will be 0 if there were no matching rows, however it will also be 0 if `UPDATE` simply did not change anything. So is there a way to know that row being updated does not exist without using additional query?

Comment: your question has its own answer.

Comment: It looks like this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794924/how-to-know-if-a-mysql-update-query-fails-because-information-being-supplied-mat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Given your exact question, there is no way to know what exactly the 0 means without an additional query.

Answer (score 1):

Just check number of rows return by `update` and do handle it by custom message/error reporting using your programming language (JAVA/PHP/ etc..)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you may add a special field which is always subject to update, for example `last_updated = NOW()`